# Analytics demographics do not appear

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

I performed from outside the whole procedure of google.

I inserted the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var _gaq = _gaq || [];
        _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-xxxxxxxx-x']);
        _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
        (function() {
            var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
            ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') + 'stats.g.doubleclick.net/dc.js';
            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
        })();
    </script>
```

I activated the option in the menu administration and validated the code.

Now it's been a week and still do not see anything.

When within the pages:

Demographics-> ...

Interest-> ...

I do not see any statistics, only one entry in yellow that says:

`Some data in this report may not have been removed When a threshold was applied.`

But I have not applied any threshold!

Did I forget something?

How do I view that data?

Comment: You probably have very few visits. Wait a little until the amount of data is above the [threshold](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2954071?hl=en).

Comment: Nope, not necessarily. I get this mention on a high trafic website.